# Directx11 where initialize constant shader buffer

Tags: buffer, shader, directx-11

I not know where initialize shader constant buffer: before `Map()`, before `Unmnap()` or is not difference where initialize ?

Answer (score 0):

See second parameter of the create buffer function.

```
ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(
  [in]             const D3D11_BUFFER_DESC *pDesc,
  [in, optional]   const D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA *pInitialData,
  [out, optional]  ID3D11Buffer **ppBuffer
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476501(v=vs.85).aspx